# jquery add class to main menu <li> by click sub menu <li> a (anchor)

Tags: jquery

I want if I click on sub menu **service1** than anchor of **service1** should add class "**active**" and main menu **service** anchor add class "**active-main**".

In css I have two class **.active** have green background and **.active-main** have blue background.

[image]

```js
jQuery(function(){

  var url = window.location.pathname,
      urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there

  // now grab every link from the navigation
  jQuery('ul.nav li a').each(function(){

    // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
    if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
      jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.active{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:green;
}

.active-main{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="service.html">Service</a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="service1.html">Service 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="service2.html">Service 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1> Service 1 </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav ul li a").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $('li').removeClass('active-main');
    $(this).addClass("active");
    //var parentul = $(this).closest("ul");
    //var parentli = $(parentul).closest('li');
    //$($(parentli).get(0)).addClass('active-main');
$($($(this).closest("ul").closest('li')).get(0)).addClass('active-main');

    });
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/238qywpq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $('li').removeClass('active-main');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').closest('.nav > li').addClass('active-main');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afcmfvzz/